# A $3 \times 3$ matrix having integral entries

Tags: matrices

A is a $3 \times 3$ matrix having integral entries such that $det(A)=120$, number of such matrices is?

Could someone help me as how approach this question?

Comment: The question is vague i think there should be a range for entries like $[0-10]$ or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Infinite. Take $n$ to be any integer in the following:

$\begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 & 1\\ n & 5 & 0 \\ n & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$